# Need to find out why my Ubuntu is repeatedly trying to create a hotspot

Tags: systemd, ap-hotspot

I was trying to understand high memory and CPU usage, so I did `journatctl -f` and found this in the result:

```
Feb 06 13:16:18 arrakis create_ap[393537]: ERROR: 'wlan0' is not a WiFi interface
Feb 06 13:16:18 arrakis systemd[1]: create_ap.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 06 13:16:18 arrakis systemd[1]: create_ap.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 06 13:16:23 arrakis systemd[1]: create_ap.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 93087.
Feb 06 13:16:23 arrakis systemd[1]: Stopped Create AP Service.
Feb 06 13:16:23 arrakis systemd[1]: Started Create AP Service.
Feb 06 13:16:24 arrakis create_ap[393578]: ERROR: 'wlan0' is not a WiFi interface
Feb 06 13:16:24 arrakis systemd[1]: create_ap.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 06 13:16:24 arrakis systemd[1]: create_ap.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 06 13:16:29 arrakis systemd[1]: create_ap.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 93088.
Feb 06 13:16:29 arrakis systemd[1]: Stopped Create AP Service.
Feb 06 13:16:29 arrakis systemd[1]: Started Create AP Service.
Feb 06 13:16:29 arrakis create_ap[393620]: ERROR: 'wlan0' is not a WiFi interface
Feb 06 13:16:29 arrakis systemd[1]: create_ap.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 06 13:16:29 arrakis systemd[1]: create_ap.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 06 13:16:34 arrakis systemd[1]: create_ap.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 93089.
Feb 06 13:16:34 arrakis systemd[1]: Stopped Create AP Service.
Feb 06 13:16:34 arrakis systemd[1]: Started Create AP Service.
Feb 06 13:16:34 arrakis create_ap[393663]: ERROR: 'wlan0' is not a WiFi interface
Feb 06 13:16:34 arrakis systemd[1]: create_ap.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 06 13:16:34 arrakis systemd[1]: create_ap.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

● create_ap.service - Create AP Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/create_ap.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-02-07 02:14:28 CET; 3s ago
    Process: 659956 ExecStart=/usr/bin/create_ap --config /etc/create_ap.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 659956 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Also, doing ´sudo systemctl disable create_ap.service´ did not fix it.

How I find out where this is coming from? I mean why is my system repeatedly trying to create a hotspot. I don't need a hotspot, how do I stop this?

Output of ´systemctl sttus create_ap.service´ :

Comment: `create_ap.service` is trying to create an access point.  Unless this is what you want, you can disable the service with `sudo systemctl disable create_ap.service`

Comment: @user535733 I updated the question

Comment: Next, show us the complete output of `dpkg -S /usr/lib/systemd/system/create_ap.service`

Comment: @user535733 `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/systemd/system/create_ap.service`

Comment: Next, please [edit your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1314110/edit) to show us the complete output of `cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/create_ap.service`

Comment: I deleted the conf file for create_ap.service and now problem is gone after restart. Thanks for your help.